# Confusing behaviour of localeCompare with sort

Tags: javascript, sorting

So when I try to sort alphabets with just sort, it works as expected like:

```
['a', 'A'].sort().join('') // 'Aa'
```

However, when I use localeCompare with sort, it doesn't work as expected:

```
['a', 'A'].sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b)).join('') // 'aA'
```

OR

```
['a', 'b', 'A', 'c', 'b', 'A', 'B'].sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b)).join('')

// 'aAAbbBc'
```

Why doesn't the sort place uppercase letters like 'A' before lowercase case letters as would have happened when using just sort() with no arguments ? I'm trying to sort the letters in ascending order (lexicographically).Thanks!

Comment: Well, what locale are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The two are indeed not guaranteed to use the same algorithm for string comparison:

[ECMAScript on `localeCompare`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/text-processing.html#sec-string.prototype.localecompare) has:

> The two Strings are compared in an implementation-defined fashion.
>
> [...]
>
> This function is intended to rely on whatever language-sensitive comparison functionality is available to the ECMAScript environment from the host environment, and to compare according to the rules of the host environment's current locale.

[ECMAScript on `sort`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.sort) on the other hand has this step in its procedure:

> Let xSmaller be ! IsLessThan(xString, yString, true).

`isLessThan` is defines the comparison in specific terms (referring to code points), and it is the same procedure that is used for determining whether `a < b`.

This should explain why there can be a difference.

### A callback function that is equivalent

If you are looking for a sort callback function that will have the same effect as when you would not have provided one, then go for this one:

```js
let cmp = (a, b) => (String(a) > String(b)) - (String(a) < String(b));

// Demo
let arr = ['a', 'A', undefined, 4, NaN, Infinity, null];
let sorted1 = [...arr].sort(cmp);
let sorted2 = [...arr].sort();

console.log(sorted1);
console.log(sorted2);
```